# Object mapping: Promise.all to catch iteration end and error

Tags: javascript

Let's say I want to perform a function on every value of an object.

How can I catch the end of the iteration and to know that no error has been made running the function on each value?

```
Object.keys(result).map(function(key, index) {
  var value = result[key];

  functiontorun(value, (result, error) => {
     if (error) {
     // catch the error
     }
  });

  // AT THE END OF THE ITERATION               
     // if no error at all => then something
     // if at least one error => then something else


});
```

Comment: Do you mean "at the end of the iteration" (checks many times), or "after the end of the mapping function" (checks once)?

Comment: Since you seem to be asking about an asynchronous function, use promises.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I mean when the function has been running on every values (no more value to pass into the function).

Comment: @Ontokrat is the function to run asynchronous, as seems to be implied? (If so, `.map` will only work if you're trying to create an array of promises)

Comment: @CertainPerformance you mean https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @Bergi Want to make a response? `promises` are not my best friends...

Comment: @Ontokrat Are you even `map`ping anything in your code? It doesn't look like you're assigning the result to anything

Comment: @CertainPerformance In fact I just need to loop a function on every value of an object (named result)

Comment: `map` is not the right method to use if you don't intend to transform the input array into another - generally use `forEach` instead.

Comment: You want to do something at the end of all iterations or each iteration?

Comment: @Carr at the end of all iterations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn each request into a promise, and use `Promise.all` on the result:

```
const allPromises = Object.keys(result).map(function(key, index) {
  var value = result[key];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    functiontorun(value, (result, error) => {
      if (error) {
        // catch the error
        reject(error);
      } else resolve();
    });
  });
});
Promise.all(allPromises)
  .then(() => console.log('all successful'))
  .catch(err => console.log('at least one error ' + err));
```

Comment: `functiontorun` runs ok, but no console.log is ever printed (`then` or `catch`)

Comment: Can you post your actual code? (did you make sure to `resolve()`?)

Comment: My bad, `functiontorun`was not returning any callback.

Comment: No, `catch` is a *method* of a `Promise` - it's different from the `catch` keyword.

Comment: strange, my code break without `{}`... Anyway, It works fine with. Thanks.